# Interface treated differently than equivalent object

Tags: typescript

In the snippet below, the two seemingly equivalent lines at the end apparently are not. I want to write my function definition such a way that neither gives an error, and both return `(string | number)[]`. Any ideas?

```
function keyableValues<T extends Record<any, keyof any>>(o: T): T[keyof T][] {
    const values: T[keyof T][] = [];
    for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
        values.push(o[key as keyof T]);
    }
    return values;
};

interface O {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}
let asInterface: O = { a: 'hi', b: 2 };
const notAsInterface = { a: 'hi', b: 2 };

keyableValues(asInterface);    // <- typing error, returns (string | number | symbol)[]
keyableValues(notAsInterface); // <- no error, returns (string | number)[]
```

The error on the second-to-last line is:

> Argument of type 'O' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record'.
>
> Index signature is missing in type 'O'.(2345)

[Here it is in the typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAawKYE8CGAjANqgNU1xFQGcAeAFUVQA8pUwATMxAJVQjgCdmLMYdABoUGOMESD0APhkAKOAC5EVAJQqqAbTToJqgLpaDiAN4AoRFcTcwZKIgBuxUmU07xkqkZMBeRMYA3JbWwLyI8rb2YuiI+gDy2ABWXFAAdADmqFDxAO5gAAo8cAAOqDxQ6ABymAC25IpqamYh1tbOJORpJSBkABaKHrGYbLr63mrBbQC+rYg82SA8SB2uwdPB5jBgjDzAmBCoiPEtbZgq9jzbGVPW2CpgILXY5evm+A4jAJI75fuHKhO-lMUhUAHI+jAwaJ7ogAEyIDbmKIOMBwKAAQTIP12-yOwNBiAhUJhKgRSPMuhw+CInTI8m+vz2B1QkzaAHp2YgKABaRCVErXWg8Yo8UQLKBLOwRS5CgA+iEez3KiAVZHQzzguDUxkpGGphBcDTRmOxTLxbM53L5aOFovFi2WbHksrAGVViqeLx4OoM5iAA).

**Edit**
Please note this is a simplified example. It is important to maintain the restriction on values to be assignable to `keyof any`. My real use case is a function that maps the values in a collection to the keys of a new object:

```
function mapAsKeys<T extends Record<any, keyof any>, V>(
  object: T,
  iteratee: ObjectIteratee<T, V>,
): Record<T[keyof T], V>;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript doesn't assign with interface while assign with object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446026/typescript-doesnt-assign-with-interface-while-assign-with-object-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better or worse, interface types don't get implicit index signatures, whereas type aliases do.  See the relevant GitHub issue [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) for more information.

My suggestion here is to use a self-referential generic constraint instead, where `T extends Record<keyof T, ...>`, which should be true for any object type whether it's an interface or a type alias.  Like this:

```
function keyableValues<T extends Record<keyof T, keyof any>>(o: T): T[keyof T][] {
    const values: T[keyof T][] = [];
    for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
        values.push(o[key as keyof T]);
    }
    return values;
};
```

That should fix the issue:

```
keyableValues(asInterface);    // <- no error, returns (string | number)[]
keyableValues(notAsInterface); // <- no error, returns (string | number)[]
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAawKYE8CGAjANqgNU1xFQGcAeAFUVQA8pUwATMxAJVQjgCdmK06OMERUANCgzDEmMOgB88gBRwAXKICU6qgG1B0qgF0dhxAG8AUImuJuYMlEQA3YqTLa9UkUZOIAvIgmANxWNsC8iEp2DpLoiNIA8tgAVlxQAHQA5qhQCQDuYAAKPHAADqg8UOgAcpgAtuQqGhrmoTY2LiTk6aUgZAAWKp5xmGz63oYaIe0Avm2IPDkgPEidbiEzIRYwYIw8wJgQqIgJre2Y6g48O5nTNtjqYCB12BUbFviOowCSuxUHR3UpwCZhk6gA5P0YOCJA9EAAmRCbCzRRxgOBQACCZF+ewBxxBYMQkOhsPUiORFkEOHwRC6ZCUPz++0OqCm7QA9BzEBQALSIdG0HglHgSRZQZb2SJXG6IAA+Auerx4GhMVIwNMIrka6KxOOZ+PZXJ5-MFFRFYqWKzYShlYEy8sVLwqqsMFiAA)

Comment: Fantastic! That does exactly what I needed. Very unintuitive ... I would never have assumed that was even legal, let alone useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Record` for this; `keyof` is enough.

```js
function keyableValues<T>(o: T): T[keyof T][] {
    const values: T[keyof T][] = [];
    for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
        values.push(o[key as keyof T]);
    }
    return values;
};

interface O {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}
let asInterface: O = { a: 'hi', b: 2 };

let result = keyableValues(asInterface);
```

Then the type of `result` is inferred as `(string | number)[]`.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this! A difference here is that you've removed the restriction for the values to be assignable to `keyof any`. In my effort to make a simplified example, I didn't keep that need clear at all. Sorry about that! I'll update the question.

Comment: Ah, in that case there's a problem because the type you want inferred for the array elements - `(string | number)` - isn't usable as the type of the keys in an object, even though `string` and `number` each are individually. Try writing `type X = { [k: string|number]: any }` and you'll see it gives an error: "An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead."

Comment: I'm not following your suggestion yet to consider using a mapping object type. Can you elaborate? And does it explain why the one that does not implement an interface works fine?

Comment: That's not my suggestion; it's just Typescript's error message when you try to use `string|number` as a key type.