# Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type. Work with type but not with interface

Tags: typescript

I don't really know why but I'm facing to an issue about type/interface that I cannot understand.

```
interface A {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

type B = {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

type Params = Record<string, string>
const hello = (arg: Params) => arg

const a: A = {a: '', b: ''}
const b: B = {a: '', b: ''}

hello(a) // Argument of type 'A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Params'.
  // Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'A'.(2345)
hello(b)
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmQGcwpQBzAGhzwCMjTyQKsBfLLMATwAcUAQsgC8mWrkIkylGnmQMpzVhy58UABThQ4AW2IjkAJQgIA9lAAmAHiYzFlAHyczIUsgAWEADZfTBgBRaFESa2noAlCIO+FCsWC5ukuiiGJIA5GlU8kQZHAlg2chCKemZhbmcnj6mgeFYVb7+dOFAA

The issue can be solve by using type instead of interface, but I cannot explain why !

For me the interface A should fit the Params type.

The issue to fix that is to use Type or use the solution bellow

```
hello({...a})
```

Comment: Related: [TypeScript doesn't assign with interface while assign with object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46446026) | [Interfaces vs Types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37233735) |